# Which browsers do not support user-defined tags?

Tags: css, html5, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I recently added HTML5 `<nav>` and `<footer>` elements to a page, thinking that HTML5-capable browsers would use them for semantic things like navigation, while older browsers would see them as user-defined tags and apply CSS styles to them like ordinary `<div>` elements.

When I was working on this, I remember seeing a warning that a version or some versions of Internet Explorer didn't support user-defined tags, with a link to [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) as a possible solution. Unfortunately I don't remember where I saw it or which version/versions might be affected (which would indicate how concerned I should be about this problem).

If other common browsers share this problem, it would help to know about those too.

Comment: take a look here http://html5test.com

Comment: The title does not match the content. The title says “user-defined”, but the text refers to HTML5 tags.

Comment: See these recent related questions: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57805/when-updating-to-html5-will-adding-doctype-html-article-and-microdata-re and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57726/can-changing-websites-from-xhtml-1-0-to-html5-affect-rendering-in-older-browsers.

Comment: ^^ The HTML5 tags are user-defined tags when there is no HTML5 support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com) website is excellent to determine browser support for various features, including HTML5 semantic tags:

http://caniuse.com/html5semantic

You'll see that IE8 and below let the team down. If you need to support IE6, 7, and 8, then using the HTML5 shiv is a good idea. IE8 is still in use by roughly 7% of visitors, according to [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201301-201401), but that percentage may be higher for some audiences. It's worth checking your own stats if you have them and making a decision based on that.

Comment: I thought about it and decided that this technically doesn't answer my question, but it's close enough. I can deduce from that page which browsers support user-defined tags because "partial support" is defined as allowing the style to be set manually, strongly implying that styles can be set to any tag that isn't fully supported.

Comment: caniuse is never up to date, so typically its wrong. the best place to determine browser features and support? the browser's documentation. aka msdn, mdn, opera, apple, and google.dev.

Comment: @albert The data that backs Can I Use is open source and published on [GitHub](https://github.com/fyrd/caniuse). It's updated pretty regularly. If you find inaccuracies you can always contribute corrections there.

Comment: i'm very well aware. its a great tool...but its not the source, and i've found plenty of inconsistencies.